# How can I conduct a factor analysis in a survey that happened through 10 years?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

I've applied a FA in a survey that happened in 2002. However, that same survey was reused in 2005, 2008 and 2012. How can I incorporate the time effect in the FA?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply include a `year` variable for every record in the survey and re-run your analysis. If time has a strong effect on the survey records, this will be reflected in your factor analysis.